# React-native-elements searchbar ignoring styles

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

Using `"expo": "^32.0.0","react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",` In my component I am using `containerStyle` and `inputStyle` but the [searchbar](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.1/searchbar.html#usage) remains the same. How can I style it?

```
<SearchBar
    placeholder="Type Here..."
    onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
    inputStyle={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
    containerStyle={{
      backgroundColor: "white",
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderRadius: 5
    }}
    placeholderTextColor={"#g5g5g5"}
    placeholder={"Pritish Vaidya"}
    value={search}
  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inputContainerStyle={{... }}
```

is what you are looking for

You can find more [here](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar.html#inputcontainerstyle)

Comment: still doesnt pick up styles

Comment: just replace inputstyle with inputContainerStyle